# Jenkins cannot recognize sh.exe although added to path

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to run a pipeline with `sh` instead of `bat` on Windows.

I have added the following paths in the global properties:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\bin
```

but it still does not work.

When I run the pipeline, I get the following error message:

```
[pipeline] sh
/usr/bin/sh: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe: Command not found
[pipeline] }
```

Note that the file `sh.exe` is located in the folder `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\`

However, if I use a Freestyle project with `Execute Shell`, it works correctly.

What else can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Could the space in `Program Files` cause any issues? `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe:` Can you try moving to a different location that doesn't have spaces in the Path?

Comment: You're right, turns out that the space was causing the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the space in `Program Files` was the one that was causing problems when trying to run the pipeline. Therefore `sh.exe` was not found in `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\`.

So I had to move `Git\bin` location somewhere else where there are no spaces in the path.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to set the path variable when the pipeline is running. So basically you run this batch command within your pipeline:

```
SET PATH=PATH;"C:\Program Files\Git\bin"
```

and now, if you were to run `sh` as a batch command, it should refer to the `sh.exe` in `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin`